# function to check if the element at given position in given array of integers is bigger than its two neigbours

Tags: javascript

I am adding my question here as well as in the title:
function to check if the element at given position in given array of integers is bigger than its two neighbours.
Here is my sample code:

```
`var dTest = new Array();

 dTest[0] = 1;
 dTest[1] = 2;
 dTest[2] = 3;
 dTest[3] = 4;
 dTest[4] = 5;

for (i=0;i<11;i++){

    if(dTest[i]>dTest[i+1] && dTest[i]>[i-1])

    {
        console.log("");
    }

    else 

    {
        console.log("");
    }

};`
```

So what I am trying is written in the tittle. Thx :)

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters, for some reason your `for` loop is going until `11` (magic number? why 11, it makes no sense). Change your loop to run for the length of the array, then check to see if a number even exists to the "left" or "right", if so, then do logic:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dTest.length; i++) {
    if (dTest[i-1] != undefined && dTest[i+1] != undefined) {
        //this position has neighbors!
        var current = dTest[i];
        if (current > dTest[i-1] && current > dTest[i+1]) {
            console.log(current + " is bigger than it's neighbors!");
        } else {
            console.log(current + " is smaller than it's neighbors!");
        }
    } else {
        console.log(dTest[i] + " doesn't have enough neighbors!");
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NFHTg/

Comment: Ok, thank you. I believe this is the right solution. Also gives me the option for "no neighbours", thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with checking indexes in your array that don't exist. This solution should fix it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dTest.length; i++) {
    if ((dTest[i-1] != undefined && dTest[i-1] > dTest[i]) ||
        (dTest[i+1] != undefined && dTest[i+1] > dTest[i])) {
         console.log('Element at position ' + i + ' is not bigger than his neighbours');
    } else {
         console.log('Element at position ' + i + ' is bigger than his neighbours');
    }
}
```